# Set gnu screen title within ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

On my local machine, window titles within screen update nicely to the pwd. I have

```
shelltitle '% |bash'
```

in my .screenrc. Yet when I ssh to another host, the window title remains as the pwd from where I ran the ssh command, rather than updating to be the pwd within my ssh session.

How can I make my screen window title relative to my ssh session?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the window title of the current screen session with `echo -en "\033kNEW TITLE\033\134"`. On your local machine you have probably some code in your ~/.bashrc oder in some global config file (the location can depend on OS flavor) which changes the title accordingly, e.g. in your prompt setting; try `echo $PS1`.

So, you have to modify the remote `~/.bashrc`, too. A good starting point can be

```
PS1='\033k\u@\h: \w\033\134\u@\h:\w > '
```

which will display a prompt like `user@machine:~ >` and sets the screen title to `user@machine:~`.

Please be aware, that this will not change the title of your *terminal* window. The command for that is `echo -ne "\033]0;SOMETHING\007"`.